# Cannot add an edge/path/vertex to a tree

Tags: r, igraph

Following is my code to add a vertex to my tree.

```
library(igraph);
g <- graph.empty(directed=FALSE) + "a"; // works!
g <- g + path("b", "c"); // error!
```

I have tried `add_edges` too, but it does not work. I get the error `Error in as.igraph.vs(e1, toadd) : Invalid vertex names`.

Comment: Since you are using named vertices, I believe you need to define them first with `g<- add_vertices(g, 2, name=c("b", "c"))` then the `add_edges` function will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can't `add_edges` unless the nodes already exist. I think that what you are looking for is:

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph.empty(directed=FALSE) + "a"
g = g + "b" + "c"
g <- add_edges(g, c("b", "c"))
plot(g)
```

[image: Graph with added Edge]